# Как запустить проект Spring MVC в IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, spring-mvc

Создал простенький проект в IntelliJ IDEA. У меня есть `WEB-INF`, контроллер, модель. При нажатии **`run`** появляется **`edit configurations`**. **`Build`** выполнился без ошибок.

Вопрос: как запустить проект, чтобы в браузере открылся `index.jsp`?

[image: Структура проекта]

Comment: А система сборки какая? Maven или gradle?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб не знаю что это такое и как подключить в IntelliJ, разве сборкой не ide занимается?

Comment: Сборкой занимается система сборки. IDE только стартует сборку через указанную систему, которой ещё надо объяснить что и как собирать. По идее она у вас какая-то есть, иначе у вас бы не компилировалось ничего, т.к. надо много зависимостей подключить.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если появляется edit configurations, то далее надо выбрать new далле из списка выбрать сервер `Tomcat` к примеру, локальный. Tomcat надо инсталлировать отдельно. Указать путь к нему. На вкладке deployment выбрать артифакт, который надо собирать при запуске.

Comment: Мне помогла вот эта серия постов http://www.geekabyte.io/2015/07/introduction-to-servlet-based-web.html и вот этот гайд https://spring.io/guides/gs/serving-web-content/